# A question using Baire Category Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

If $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is a smooth function and assume that $f$ restricted to $[a;b]$ is not a polynomial for all intervals $[a; b]\subset \mathbb{R}$  with $a < b$.

Prove that there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ so that for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $f^{(i)}(x_0)\neq 0$. We are given a hint that we can use the Baires Category Theorem:
$$
\mathbb{R} = \bigcup\limits_{k\in\mathbb{N}}A_k
$$
then there exist $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and  interval $I = [s, t]$ with $s < t$ such that $I \subset A_{k_0}$. Please help me out!

Thank you.

Comment: Exactly the same http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial

Comment: Also you must say that set $A_k$ are closed.